# Do we really need an [oauth] and an [oauth-2.0] tag?

Tags: discussion, status-declined, tag-synonym-process

If you look at the descriptions for the two tags they are very similar.

[oauth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/oauth)

> OAuth (Open Authorization) is a specification for client applications to access protected resources on behalf of a user. It was developed as an alternative to users handing out their login credentials to third-party applications.

[oauth-2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/oauth-2.0)

> OAuth (Open Authorization) is an open protocol framework to allow secure API authorization in a simple and standardized way for desktop, mobile and web applications. OAuth 2.0 is the second version of the OAuth protocol.

[image]

We can even check Wikipedia to see what they do - [OAuth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OAuth). Then check the [OAuth2 page](https://en.wikipedia.org/?title=OAuth2&redirect=no) - back to a section on the OAuth page.

I would like to suggest we add a synonym [oauth-2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/oauth-2.0) tag and just go with [oauth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/oauth).

Comment: Hmm,  on Stack Apps we also have those two tags but we kept oauth2 and synonymized oauth into it: https://stackapps.com/tags/oauth2/synonyms

Comment: I considered that but i am considered anyone using for example twitters oauth1 implementation may get confused.    Then there is issues with things that use client_Credeintals or service accounts.  which are also not technically Oauth2.   Oauth2 referrers to the three legged oauth flow there are other flows another example thats not strictly oauth2 would be password flow if you are crazy enough to still be using that. 

Comment: When you have to use the words "not technically" then you are probably in a minority for thinking that; whether you are correct or not is not really relevant. The tag should represent what the majority thinks when they see "oauth2".

Comment: @Gimby I am more then happy to go with what the consensus aggress with. However if we have a synonym to OAuth from Oauth2,  then the masses wont know the difference they will happy type oauth2 and get the OAuth tag.  That's the beauty of synonyms.   Labeling something Oauth2 that is not strictly OAuth2 would be incorrect and lead to confusion (IMO).   Labeling everything OAuth will encompass the full spectrum of OAuth related topics.   Where OAuth2 is just a subset.

Comment: Currently a large number of the questions tagged OAuth are in fact Oauth2 questions.  This is because a lot of documentation doesn't mention OAuth2 they just say OAuth.

Comment: There isn't really an OAuth2 page on Wikipedia. There ***was*** an OAuth2 page on Wikipedia, but now it is a redirect.

Comment: OAuth 1.x and OAuth 2.x are not compatible, so we should probably keep the two tags.

Comment: I’d suggest creating an oath-1.0 tag and carefully retagging.